# Programming a new random effects structure in lme

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I am seeking advice on programming a new random effects variance-covariance matrix/structure (pdmat) in R for use in lme()?  I've checked out the lme source code (as suggested if you want to program your own pdmat), but remain confused.  Does anyone have a good reference?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pinheiro/Bates is the classic reference but doesn't have the details on how to do this; I had to do it once and basically ended up copying the code from one of the existing structures and changing it to meet my needs.  It was trickier than I expected to be, though, and long enough now that I don't quite remember what I did.  I too hope someone knows of a better reference.

Comment: Great question. Me too interesting in learning this. Would appreciate @Aaron if you advise us.